# Installing a x86 image in new sdk tools v12

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, qemu, android-sdk-tools

I've upgraded to android sdk tools 12.
As a release note google says: 
The AVD manager and emulator can now use system images compiled for ARM v7 and x86 CPUs.

Has anyone tried to run a x86 image? Are there any 3.0+ images?

Thanks,

Comment: Tried it but could not create a new avd to run on x86. And there is nothing in the "./android create avd" options.

Comment: someone from Google replied on android developers google group:   build the AOSP source tree using the "full_x86-eng" product, then launch 
"emulator". 
Warning: this is currently *not* faster than ARM emulation (but we're 
working on it).

Comment: Look [here](http://vladnevzorov.com/2011/02/08/android-os-build-options/) for instructions on how to build the ASOP with full_x86-eng.    I will give it a go later on this day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few months passed, the source code for the android 4.0 was released and I find that the x86 virtual machines are faster than any solution I tried which used the Android Emulator.

You can find instructions on using android x86 images here: http://www.android-x86.org/

Answer (score 6):

In the GUI of the SDK for emulator configuration, the **CPU type** drop down box is disabled. Probably this is something they are preparing for the release 13 of the Android SDK tools. (it is also possible that non of my installed platform revision have x86 images)

I tried to run one of my emulator images as x86 explicitly, and get this:

```
C:\Program Files\Android-SDK\tools>emulator-x86.exe -avd HTC_Magic
qemu: linux kernel too old to load a ram disk C:\Program Files\Android-SDK/platf
orms\android-4\images\/kernel-qemu, C:\Program Files\Android-SDK/add-ons\addon_g
oogle_apis_google_inc_4\images\/ramdisk.img, qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=
ttyS1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1 ndns=2
```

I think the emulator image needs to be created explicitly for x86... Would be nice to have an x86 image so the performance of underlining qemu goes up, as it will not need to emulate ARM CPU instruction set...

Comment: Then why did Google released SDK tool r12? This is the only change according to the release notes.

Comment: As it is advertised, the major improvement of the new version of SDK tools is the ability to emulate x86 compiled images. But when you create a new avd, the CPU type option is disabled when any API target is selected.

Comment: I think they released this becouse of ADT 12 plugin for eclipse release, that has lot of changes for development. Probably they will release x86 platform images for the SDK tools r12 some time in the future...

Answer (score 5):

You can already run http://www.android-x86.org/ and connect to it with adb over tcpip right now. You do not need the SDK support for it. And it is very fast.

Otherwise if you install the Google TV add on on linux you can create a Google TV avd and that will use x86. It really works nicely only on Linux though since that is where it is tunneled to the hypervisor properly.

There are various blog post around on how to set that up properly e.g. http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/09/01/google-tv-emulator-seemingly-pointless.html

Answer (score 1):

You should install Intel® Atom™ Android x86 Emulator Image.

You could find detailed instructions at [this link](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-the-intel-atom-tm-android-x86-emulator-image-add-on-from-the-android-sdk-manager/)

Comment: With ADT rev 17 it is integrated. See 
http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2012/03/updated-sdk-tools-and-adt-revision-17.html
and 
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own android x86 emulator from the AOSP.  Here are the instructions from the Intel website:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-ia-emulator-gingerbread/

Answer (score 0):

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-virtual-device-emulation-for-ia/

updated article provides info about using 3.2 images, perhaps my sdk does not offer such choice (tested 2.3.3, 3.2 and 4.0.3)

more likely the article refers to an intel based sdk build, that is not the one provided by android developer site.

They may add intel images (yet it's true the emulator needs x86 based images) later and support also intel abi

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-ia-emulator-gingerbread/) and was able to build a working x86 image. It runs great, much faster than ARM emulation, provided kvm is enabled, which you can by doing "sudo apt-get install kvm" on Ubuntu machines. To check if kvm is already on your machine, do an lsmod | grep kvm.

To answer the other question, Google hasn't released any images with it's SDK yet and this is the thread where someone from Google responded to my [question](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ee043711a3084195/c2484ec33729b995?lnk=gst&q=sk.anirudh@gmail.com#c2484ec33729b995) about it.

They plan to release Gingerbread images pretty soon. Which is why there is no drop down option saying "Intel" or x86 in the CPU box of the Android tool (yet).